# Dirichlet problem's solution on $[0,1]$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The Dirchlet problem on $[0,1]$ is 
$$\begin{cases}{\Delta f=g}&\text{on } & (0,1) \\f(0)=a & \text{and}& f(1)=b \end{cases}$$
Where $\Delta=\frac{d^2}{dt^2}$. The unique solution of this problem
$$f(x)=\int_0^x (x-t) g(t)dt -x\int_0^1(1-t)g(t)dt+a+(b-a)x$$

Does anyone know an elementary prove of this fact? References, hins or solutions are welcome!

Comment: In that case you have just an ordinary differential equation with right hand side $g$. So integrate two times and plug in the boundary conditions and you should end up with that formula

Comment: I have a doubt with that process, how can I split the double integral involved in the solution?

Comment: @user16015 I don't want to prove that $f$ is a solution but $f$ is the unique solution.

Comment: Since it is a linear problem assume that there is another solution. Consider the difference of the two solutions $\tilde{u}$. Then this difference satisfies the homogeneous Laplace equation, meaning $\tilde{u}''=0$ with boundary conditions both zero. The homogeneous equation you can now easily solve by integration two times. You get a linear function with two coefficients. Plugging in the boundary conditions gives just the zero solution, therefore, there the solution is unique.

Comment: Nice, thanks. If I want to figure it out the solution. How do I must proceed?

Comment: you mean the given solution? I think you can really process like I suggested. To get rid of the double integral you have to change the order of integration one time. On the other hand, you could just very that $f(x)$ is a solution, and by uniqueness you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noting $y''(x)=g(x)$, one has
$$ y'(x)=y'(0)+\int_0^xg(t)dt $$
and hence
\begin{eqnarray}
y(x)&=&y(0)+y'(0)x+\int_0^x\int_0^tg(s)dsdt\\
&=&y(0)+y'(0)x+\int_0^x\int_s^xg(s)dtds\\
&=&a+y'(0)x+\int_0^x(x-s)g(s)ds.
\end{eqnarray}
Using $y(1)=b$, one have
$$ b=a+y'(0)+\int_0^1(1-s)g(s)ds$$
or
$$y'(0)=b-a-\int_0^1(1-s)g(s)ds.$$
So
\begin{eqnarray}
y(x)&=&a+(b-a-\int_0^1(1-s)g(s)ds)x+\int_0^x(x-s)g(s)ds\\
&=&a+(b-a)x-x\int_0^1(1-s)g(s)ds+\int_0^x(x-s)g(s)ds
\end{eqnarray}